# Anfroid Media PLayer

Tags: android

Как решить проблему? Я запрашиваю продолжительность времени трека раньше,чем медиаплеер получает эти данные.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        Button btn;
        int totalDur=0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            initPlayer();



            btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Uri uri=Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/media/1");
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    Log.d("myTag", String.valueOf(totalDur));

                }
            });


        }

       public void initPlayer()
       {
    //       mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
    //               PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
           mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           //set listeners
           mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
       }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            //mp.reset();
            mp.start();
            totalDur=mp.getDuration();
            Log.d("myTag", "onP " + String.valueOf(mp.getDuration()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ.Как один из параметров -- передал виджет из основного потока, и потом в onprepared() изменил значение)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, вы можете использовать **AsyncTask**. Тогда в метод `doInBackground()` можно поместить вызов *mp.start()*, затем установить `Thread.sleep(1000); //ожидание 1 секунду`, а в методе `onPostExecute()` уже вызывать *totalDur=mp.getDuration();*

Таким образом работать основного потока не будет нарушена, а вы сможете отрегулировать длительность ожидания.

При необходимости, здесь *_http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/149-urok-86-asynctask-znakomstvo-neslozhnyj-primer.html* есть урок по работе с АсинкТаском

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: Cпасибо, а зачем Thread.sleep(1000)?)